# How to mask a password field in Jenkins Pipeline project?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

When a password property is defined in a `Jenkinsfile`:

```groovy
properties([
    parameters([
        password(name: 'KEY', description: 'Encryption key')
    ])
])
```

Jenkins prompts users to provide its value every time the pipeline is executed:

[image: Build parameters]

I want this parameter to be masked so that `echo ${KEY}` does not print the actual value passed by the user. However, at the moment echoing it prints the provided value verbatim:

```groovy
properties([
    parameters([
        password(name: 'KEY', description: 'Encryption key')
    ])
])

node {
    stage('Stage 1') {
        # Will print the actual value of the KEY, verbatim
        sh "echo ${KEY}"
    }
}
```

Also it seems that the Mask Passwords plugin does not work with Jenkins pipelines, so using that is not an option.

Is there a way to mask these password-typed parameters in the build logs?

Comment: Will it work for declarative Jenkinsfile code ? Please can you share code

Answer (score 22):

You'll want to use the [mask passwords plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin).  Here's a `Jenkinsfile` example taken from [my shared pipeline library](https://github.com/samrocketman/jervis/blob/6cad1f74d021ad5639405dcfc0d79f7c1911eabe/vars/buildViaJervis.groovy#L114-L118).

```
properties([
    parameters([
        password(name: 'KEY', description: 'Encryption key')
    ])  
])  

node {
    stage('Stage 1') {
       // Will print the masked value of the KEY, replaced with ****
       wrap([$class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', varPasswordPairs: [[var: 'KEY', password: KEY]], varMaskRegexes: []]) {
            sh "echo ${KEY}"
        }   
    }   
}
```

Other than existing suggestions on `withCredentials`, there's not much to add.  However, of you're automatically generating your jobs via templates and you're setting a default password, then you might want to make use of `hudson.util.Secret` to secure your templates.

Comment: Downvoting because mask passwords plugin is just a stupid idea. It gives a false sense of security. One can simply do `echo ${KEY} | base64`

Comment: There’s no non-“stupid idea” as you put it.  Whether you use mask passwords, credentials plugin, or withCredentials step they all do the same thing and suffer from exfiltration by an abuser.  The only real solution is temporary credentials like assume role in AWS or hashicorp vault.  Any developer with dev access can exfiltrate with their own custom maven plugin or build tool of choice.  You should humble your phrasing if you don’t want to be seen as a jerk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jenkins Credentials plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials).With this plugin you can create a credential with an ID for use in your pipeline:

The code will be:

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'pass', variable: 'password1')]) {
     echo "My password is '${password1}'!"
}
```

In your user case:

```
node {
    stage('Echo') {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'pass', variable: 'password1')]) {
            echo "'${password1}'!"
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: The password will be masked only in the withCredentials block.

Comment: How do you connect `withCredentials` to the password parameter named `KEY` in my example?

Comment: Could you please complete the answer and connect the `KEY` parameter to the `withCredentials` clause?

Comment: @Behrang The password will be masked only in the withCredentials block so you can no have a global parameters like your code. Yo can have a "global parameter" in your jenkins but you need to include withCredentials block every time that you want to use the variable.

Comment: I rephrased the question to be clearer. If you can, please provide a working `Jenkinsfile` that: 1- prompts users to enter the KEY parameter, 2- masks it in the logs. Thanks.

Comment: With credential plugin, you must lready create the credential. While the problem here, is to mask a password received as parameter.