# jenkins hide/mask password parameter in a declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Does anyone know how to hide or mask a password parameter in a declarative pipeline output?

I am using the declarative pipeline.

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mask a password field in Jenkins Pipeline project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659862/how-to-mask-a-password-field-in-jenkins-pipeline-project)